# Ввод прямоугольной матрицы без заведомо известной размерности в Python

Tags: python, input, матрицы, списки

Задание:
Напишите программу, на вход которой подаётся прямоугольная матрица в виде последовательности строк, заканчивающихся строкой, содержащей только строку "end" (без кавычек)
Программа должна вывести матрицу того же размера, у которой каждый элемент в позиции `i, j` равен сумме элементов первой матрицы на позициях `(i-1, j), (i+1, j), (i, j-1), (i, j+1)`. У крайних символов соседний элемент находится с противоположной стороны матрицы.

С алгоритмом суммы элементов я планирую справиться самостоятельно, но мне не хватает знаний языка чтобы реализовать сам ввод данных максимально лаконично и без лишних костылей

Пример ввода:

> 9 5 3
>
> 0 7 -1
>
> -5 2 9
>
> end

Пример вывода:

> 3 21 22
>
> 10 6 19
>
> 20 16 -1

Answer (score 1):

Если без обработки ошибок:

```
mat = []
while True:
    s = input()
    if s == "end":
        break
    row = [int(x) for x in s.split()]
    mat.append(row)
print(mat)

1 2 3
4 5 6
end

>>[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Дописал первый ответ, продолжение считает сумму всех соседей по вертикали и горизонтали.

```
    mat = []
    while True:
        s = input()
        if s == "end":
            break
        row = [int(x) for x in s.split()]
        mat.append(row)
    for i in range(len(mat)):
        for j in range(len(mat[i])):
            x = mat[i-1][j] + mat[i-len(mat)+1][j] + mat[i][j-1] + mat[i][j-len(mat[i])+1]
            print(x, end=' ')
        print()
```